# cargo build-bpf in a sandbox environment

Tags: solana-cli, cargo

Based on the docs in order to compile the sample application, we need to use `cargo build-bpf`. Unfortunately this tool attempts to access the internet in order to download the platform tools.

Are there any docs detailing how to download its requirements and make them available so the tool does not attempt to download anything?

The justification is that unrestricted internet access is not available in a sandbox environment and for security purposes, anything downloaded must be pre-checked, therefore I'll need to provide the dependency of this tool ahead of time and place it in a directory it expects (building in a `nix` sandbox hence its trivial to provide any dependencies as long as its clear where they should be sourced)

Solana cli version: `1.16.27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cargo-build-sbf` / `cargo-build-bpf` tool will download additional files in this line: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3fa44e6fbe0c24da333f594b767eff69e0a71ec4/sdk/cargo-build-sbf/src/main.rs#L618

It's not a perfect solution, but you can download and unpack the appropriate file at https://github.com/solana-labs/platform-tools/releases/ into the directory used by `cargo build-sbf` at `~/.cache/solana/<VERSION>/platform-tools/`, where `VERSION` is a tag like `v1.37`, you should be able to replicate the same exact environment.

Comment: Thanks, the biggest issue I was facing was symlinking done to that directory from the installed sdk directory. With some patching I managed to disable that behaviour. It would have been ideal if the tool would accept env vars for the directory of platform tools and disable any symlinking

Comment: It does! Try running `cargo build-sbf -h`, and you'll see that you can set `SBF_SDK_PATH`: `--sbf-sdk <PATH> Path to the Solana SBF SDK [env: SBF_SDK_PATH=] [default: ~/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.17.17/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf]`

Comment: Indeed you can set the SDK path, but the program will try to write to that directory. Issue is the platform-tools path **must** be a symlink from home dir to sdk/dependencies/...
If platform tools dir could also be given as an input to the build, no patching would have been required

Answer (score 0):

`cargo` will auto fetch all the crates from the remote repository if they are not already available on the system in which you are building. This will happen for all the crates used within the build pipeline, including those specific to the program you are building and their dependencies.

If your concern is specifically about the solana specific crates (like `build-bpf`), you could try:

- loading the solana repo's source code into your sandbox env
- building from source IAW the solana docs
- running your `cargo build-bpf`

Either way, cargo will still attempt to fetch all the other crates that are not on your system from the remote repository

Comment: `build-bpf` itself is a script which is downloading further things (deprecated in favour of `build-sbf`). I found the logic here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/711215f83281e3a776f0e2cb7d7ec940230ee368/sdk/cargo-build-sbf/src/main.rs#L900
Its doing a lot of nasty things such as making symlinks in installed directories to HOME and adding toolchains to rustup

Comment: interesting. does `build-sbf` do any remote calls?

Comment: yes, it installs the contract dependencies so must do some remote calls as well. But that can be wrapped, biggest issue was the main wrapper which I managed to patch to stop it from downloading anything or writing to read only dirs